# AWS WebSocket API: 'Internal Server Error' with Increased Connected Clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, websocket, amazon-dynamodb

I have set up a WebSocket API on AWS with Lambda and DynamoDB following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-chat-app.html) AWS documentation.

When I test the WebSocket with just a few clients (like 2-3), everything works fine, including connections, disconnections, sending messages...

However, when I have a larger number of clients (around 150-200), I get an "Internal Server Error" message when attempting to send a message through the WebSocket API. (connect/disconnect works fine) :

> {"action": "sendmessage", "message": "hello, everyone!"}

I followed all the settings in the AWS console as per the tutorial linked above.
Do you have any idea what should be the problem?

Comment: The "Internal Server Error" with your WebSocket API on AWS may be due to resource limitations. Check Lambda function memory, DynamoDB capacity, and WebSocket connection limits. Also, review CloudWatch logs and ensure error handling is in place. Consider load testing and AWS Support if needed.

Comment: Very likely caused due to throttling on either your DynamoDB table or your Lambda. Can you check the metrics from DynamoDB, make sure there is no throttles. Also check your Lambdas, ensure there is no errors or throttling there.

Comment: Hey, there is not throttling on the DynamoDB. For Lambda I used "the app creation template for AWS CloudFormation" from the tutorial above.